# Spring SAML signature validation issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, xml-signature

I'm trying to use the Spring SAML sample app to connect to a Shibboleth IdP but have run into a signature validation issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

When the sample app gets the response from the IdP, an exception is thrown with the following:

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed
at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.doEvaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:138)
at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.evaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:107)
at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BasicSecurityPolicy.evaluate(BasicSecurityPolicy.java:51)
at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.processSecurityPolicy(BaseMessageDecoder.java:132)
at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:83)
at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80)
```

With the log containing

```
- Creating XMLSignature object
- Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org   /2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
- Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
- Signature validated with key from supplied credential
- Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
- Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
- Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
- Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
```

so it looks like the signature is being validated but the key is not trusted.  What I can't figure out is how to "establish" the trust.

I set up the sample app by

1. Copying the IdP metadata to the sample app and loading it by adding this to securityContext.xml

   ```
   <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
   <constructor-arg>
       <list>
           <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
           <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
               <constructor-arg>
                   <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                       <constructor-arg>
                           <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                       </constructor-arg>
                       <constructor-arg>
                           <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                               <constructor-arg value="/metadata/twoss-metadata.xml"/>
                           </bean>
                       </constructor-arg>
                       <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                   </bean>
               </constructor-arg>
               <constructor-arg>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                               <property name="signingKey" value="shib-signing"/>
                               <property name="trustedKeys" value="shib-signing"/>
                   </bean>
               </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
           </bean>
       </list>
   </constructor-arg>
   ```
2. Configuring the SP metadata like so

   ```
   <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
   <constructor-arg>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
               <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:dan:vancouver"/>
           <property name="extendedMetadata">
               <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                         <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                   <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
               </bean>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
   ```
3. And finally, I added the signing certificate generated during the Shibboleth installation to the sample app's keystore

   ```
   keytool -importcert -alias shib-signing -file idp-signing.crt -keystore samlKeystore.jks
   ```

   So, the question is, what do I need to do to get the trust established?

Note that both the sample app and shibboleth are in a development environment and are not using CA-signed certificates for either signing or encryption purposes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?